# SAP integration with Sharepoint 2010 and 2007

Tags: integration

AS per our requirement, we are looking forward to create a POC for SAP integration with SharePoint 2007 as well as 2010.

Could anyone please tell me what are the possible ways that I can achieve this.

Is there any difference between 2007 and 2010.

One possible way we can do is using, ASP.net connecters ...

Which option will be best ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a product called Duet that is jointly developed by the teams at MS and SAP.  http://www.duet.com/

Its sole purpose is to integrate data, content, and processes between the platforms.

Comment: Hi Mike, Is it a paid product, I afraid our client doesn't wantmore spending on this project, They are looking some Visual studio or share point internal ways to achieve this functionality !! Though +1 for this great suggestion.

Comment: Yes, it is a paid product.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2010 the Business Connectivity tooling is greatly improved and much easier to use. You will probably want to use BCS to talk to SAP through their NetWeaver Gateway add-on.

The Duet Enterprise product that Mike refers to is an additional product that does a lot of the hard work for you on both the SAP and the SharePoint side - but this could also be achieved with custom development. You will need to weigh up the licence against the likely development costs, particularly on the SAP side, as SAP skills are even more scarce than SharePoint skills.

Comment: Thank you, so what about Sap .net connector? BCS is one way we can achieve it!!

Comment: SPDoctor is completely right. The NW Gateway is the best and easiest solution for your problem.